# storing source efficiently into sql escaping

Tags: php, sql, escaping

Im having issues with storing source code into a db for a small script bin. The issue is that the printed code in the syntax highlighter used to view from the db has line breaks where it shouldnt, i have seen also in the db the text has stored in the same manner.

I have tried using severalk means to make this work, at first i thought was a wrap issue, so i set wrap to hard on the input form. Then added addslashes and that did not work, ive tried magic_quotes and in this case shown below ive tried mysql_real_escape_string and the text that comes from $content will store in the db with line breaks in places they shouldnt be.

Am i missing something? thanks

This code below is the insert into db and the value concerned is $content

```
<?php
session_start();
$submit = $_POST['submit'];
$sniptitle = ($_POST['sniptitle']);


$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); 
$user = $_SESSION['username'];
$lang = ($_POST['lang']);
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","xxxx","xxxx","xxxx");


$content = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['snipcontent']);
// ^^^HERE IS THE ISSUE ^^^                           



    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { 


                                    // Check connection
                                if (mysqli_connect_errno()) 
                                  {
                                  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
                                  }





                                mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO code_lib ( snip_title , snip_content , posted_by , lang , datetime )
                                VALUES ('$sniptitle' , '$content' , '$user' , '$lang' , '$date' )");


                                mysqli_close($con);

                                header ("Location: xxx"); // Move back to a page
                                exit();
                                }


    ?>
```

Comment: "// ^^^HERE IS THE ISSUE ^^^" - I don't think so. Did you check the value of `$_POST['snipcontent']` and `$content`?

Comment: Your mysql_real_escape_string is not going to do anything because you made your connection with mysqli.  You should be getting an error here.

Comment: yes, it contains the code and text but, there are line breaks in places there shouldnt be. example http://www.hushmag.co.uk/code/a_Snip.php?snipid=22

Comment: managed to solve with using $snipcontent = addslashes($_POST['snipcontent']);

Answer (score 0):

1. mysql_real_escape_string shouldn't be used with mysqli by any means
2. thevertheless, it shouldn't be an issue either
3. most likely your "solution" is paired with stripslashes on fetch
4. So, the right solution would be

   - turning magic quotes off
   - and using mysqli_real_escape_string